# Deleting row in a table not workng

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

I am trying to delete a row in my users_stocks table.

I use this code:

```
public bool removeStock(string user_name,string stock_symbol)
{
    user_name = user_name.Trim();
    stock_symbol = stock_symbol.Trim();
    string statement = "DELETE FROM " + "users_stocks" + " WHERE user_name = '" + user_name + "'" + " AND " + "stock_symbol = " + "'" + stock_symbol + "'" ;
    SqlCommand cmdnon = new SqlCommand(statement, connection);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        int num = cmdnon.ExecuteNonQuery();
         connection.Close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        connection.Close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

There is a row with this data, but the query wont erase it.

What am i missing?

Comment: does it give any exception when executing the procedure? what are the datatypes of `user_name` and `stock_symbol` in your table?

Comment: What is your connection string ? Are you sure it connects to the SQL Server ? Also, if there is any exception, please post it.

Comment: First I would recommend you to start using SQL parameters instead of building the SQL like that

Comment: The SQL connection string is good i am certain of it, and there is no Exception showed. the table types are nchar (except of the id int).

Comment: Look at my post below and replace the line command.Parameters.Add("@USERNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user_name.Trim(); with command.Parameters.Add("@USERNAME", SqlDbType.NChar, YOUR_LENGHT).Value = user_name.Trim();. Replace with the length set in your DB for that column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parametrized query to avoid [Sql Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and quoting problems
Not to mention that a parametrized query could be stored by the optimization engine of SqlServer and reused more quickly. An hand made query will be reevaluated every time you send to the database-

```
public bool removeStock(string user_name,string stock_symbol) 
{ 
    user_name = user_name.Trim(); 
    stock_symbol = stock_symbol.Trim(); 
    string statement = "DELETE FROM users_stocks " + 
                        "WHERE user_name = @name AND stock_symbol = @stock" ; 
    SqlCommand cmdnon = new SqlCommand(statement, connection); 
    try 
    { 
        cmdnon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", user_name);
        cmdnon.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stock", stock_symbol);
        connection.Open(); 
        int num = cmdnon.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        connection.Close(); 
        return true; 
    } 
    catch (SqlException ex) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); 
        connection.Close(); 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Luis Quijada mentioned above use parameters, they are much safer. In the code below just change the YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING value and the SqlDbType to the ones matching in your DB.

```
    public bool removeStock(string user_name, string stock_symbol)
    {
        using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING"))
        {
            using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    command.CommandText = "DELETE FROM user_stocks WHERE user_name=@USERNAME AND stock_symbol=@STOCKSYMBOL";
                    command.Parameters.Add("@USERNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user_name.Trim();
                    command.Parameters.Add("@STOCKSYMBOL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = stock_symbol.Trim();
                    connection.Open();

                    int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if (i == 0)
                        return false;

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    connection.Close();
                    return false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
  public bool removeStock(string user_name,string stock_symbol)
  {
      user_name = user_name.Trim();
      stock_symbol = stock_symbol.Trim();
      string statement = "DELETE FROM users_stocks 
                          WHERE user_name = '" + user_name + "' 
                          AND stock_symbol = '" + stock_symbol + "'" ;
      SqlCommand cmdnon = new SqlCommand(statement, connection);
      try
      {
          connection.Open();
          int num = cmdnon.ExecuteNonQuery();
          connection.Close();
          return true;
      }
      catch (SqlException ex)
      {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
          connection.Close();
          return false;
      }
  }
```

Change in query